# Symfony twig + reactJS

Tags: symfony, reactjs, twig

I would like to render a reactJS component from twig template. Is it possible?

I tried:

```
<div class="top-line">
    <h1>{{ username }}</h1>

    {% verbatim %}
    <script type="text/html" id="follow-button">
        <FriendshipButton user={{ app.user }} />
    </script>
    {% endverbatim %}
    <div id="follow-button-mp"></div>
</div>
```

And in JS side:

```
React.render(
    React.createElement(document.getElementById('follow-button').innerHTML),
    document.getElementById('follow-button-mp')
);
```

Getting an error:

```
 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: 
        <FriendshipButton user={{ app.user }} />
```

Comment: Twig doesn't know anything about JSX, so I can't see that working. Why not just declare user in your javascript using twig then mount your react component with that variable?

Comment: I added an example of how you can mount a component with a js variable from twig.

Comment: remove the verbatim tag section: the effect of verbatim is that the raw text that should not be parsed, as described in the doc http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

Answer (score 4):

Twig:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // you might have to serialise user to JSON here if you
    // want a more complete user object
    var user = '{{ app.user.id }}';

</script>
```

Javascript component (using JSX)

```
React.render(

    <FriendshipButton user={user} />,
    document.getElementById('follow-button-mp')
);
```

Comment: I was doing this until now but i was thinking if there is a way to have the templates on twig side as I tried.